# Actualizar un registro desde una transaccion laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola buenas tardes a todos, tengo una funcion que lo que hace es insertar datos en una tabla, pero necesito que al hacer el insert en la tabla "detalles" haga un update de un solo campo de otra tabla (series) y la verdad que estoy perdido en como hacerlo ya que no hay formulario de por medio para hacer la actualización (debo hacerla inmediatamente después del insert que tengo en mi transacción)...

Por ejemplo: En la vista principal van a seleccionar uno o mas productos (se van a mostrar solo los que tengan un status 0) luego cuando los inserten debo cambiar el status en la tabla "series" a 1 para que ya no esten disponibles en un proximo insert que se haga

Este es el trozo de la funcion donde realizo el insert (estoy con un while ya que pueden haber multiples datos que insertar):

```
 public function asignarSerieTecnico(Request $request){
       /*  $request->fecha_asignacion_serie = $request->get('fecha_asignacion_serie');
        $request->material_id = $request->get('material_id');
        $request->tecnico_id = $request->get('tecnico_id');
        $request->det_serializacion_id = $request->get('series');
        return response()->json(['data' => $request], 200); */
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $fecha_asignacion_serie = $request->get('fecha_asignacion_serie');
            $det_serializacion_id = $request->get('series');
            $tecnico_id = $request->get('tecnico_id');
            $usuario_id = $request->get('usuario_id');
            $material_id = $request->get('material_id');
            $cont = 0;
            while($cont < count ($det_serializacion_id)){
                $status = 1;
                $det = new TecnicoSerie();
                $det->fecha_asignacion_serie = $fecha_asignacion_serie;
                $det->det_serializacion_id = $det_serializacion_id[$cont];
                $det->tecnico_id= $tecnico_id;
                $det->usuario_id= $usuario_id;
                DB::table('det_serializacion')->where('id', $det_serializacion_id[$cont])->update(array('status' => $status));
                $det->save();

                 //ACTUALIZAR EL STATUS DE EL/LOS SERIAL(ES)
               //DB::table('det_serializacion')->where('id',$det_serializacion_id)->update(array('status' => 1));



               //DB::update('update det_serializacion set status = ? where id = ?', [$status , $det->det_serializacion_id[$cont]]);

            }

            DB::commit();
            //DB::update('update det_serializacion set status = 1 where det_serializacion_id = ', $det_serializacion_id);
            //DB::table('det_serializacion')->where('id',$det->det_serializacion_id)->update(array('status' => 1));

            return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Registro almacenado con exito');
            Alert::success('Registro Añadido con exito!!!', 'La Asignación de Series a Técnico ha sido almacenada con exito...');
            //DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
```

He intentado colocando la linea del update fuera del while y nada, ni siquiera hace el insert, solo queda en blanco el navegador...
Cualquier orientación me viene perfecta de ayuda

Comment: Hola @BetaM si claro, el tema es que estoy perdido con el tema del update porque se que debo pasarle el id de lo que quiero actualizar ademas del campo, pero realmente me perdi y en primer lugar no se si deberia ir dentro del ciclo, o crear una funcion update fuera y luego llamarla adentro

Comment: @BetaM actualize la pregunta con un ejemplo

Comment: en la funcion que tengo recupero el id para el insert dentro del while (por si hay mas de una fila que insertar) por eso creo que el update deberia ir dentro del while cierto?

Comment: Dentro del While no deberías aumentar la variable contadora? creo que estas en un loop por eso la pantalla en blanco.

Comment: si, me estaba pasando por alto el contador

Comment: Excelente amigo, entonces ya funciono tu codigo?

Comment: @DiegoReales si estimado, al parecer ya funciona ok...saludos cordiales